# html2canvas text-shadow and font-smoothing

Tags: shadow, html2canvas, stroke

I use these two types of css attributes but they won't render at all with html2canvas.

```
text-shadow: -2px 0 #e0dedb, 0 2px #e0dedb, 2px 0 #e0dedb, 0 -2px #e0dedb;

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

I read that htmlcanvas can render a text-shadow if formatted this way though:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #e0dedb;
```

But it's nowhere near the effect I need to achieve (I need a sharp stroke around my font while this is a blury shadow)

And the font-smoothing won't occur neither, so I get a very thick rendered font on all browsers that doesn't look like my font on the original webpage (well yes, it's the same one but super bold).

Is there any workaround in order to achieve these two results on the rendered image?

Comment: According to the ["README"](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas): As each CSS property needs to be manually built to be supported, there are a number of properties that are not yet supported. Note: `-moz-osx-font-smoothing` is not standard. This will probably never be supported.

Comment: That is very unfortunate. Thanks. Same for text shadows, right?

Comment: Did you try html2canvas-0.5.0-beta4 for use text-shadow?

Comment: Will check that, thank you!

Comment: Installed html2canvas-0.5.0-beta4 and tried it but the render is exactly the same.

Comment: Are you talking about `text-shadow` or `-webkit-font-smoothing` (and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing`)?

Comment: I'm talking about both. And the html2cavas file update renders the same than the previous version for both too.

Comment: I repeat `-webkit-font-smoothing` and `-moz-osx-font-smoothing` will never work, unless they become standards in all browsers and operating systems, then they will probably try to implement on html2canvas someday... Only the `text-shadow` should work, so I need to know is:
Does `text-shadow` works?

Comment: I was answering for text-shadow because that's the point you were asking me to test. Then you ask what I was talking about. Then I tell you that it doesn't work for both anyway. So no need to repeat yourself. Things are very clear for me. It seems that you needed some clarifications and I gave it to you: I tested text-shadow but neither work eventually. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tested again, only simple text-shadow work, but multiple not work, see details in project https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1111 - should be implemented

Comment: Which is exactly what I said in my initial question.

Comment: Ok, from README: **`there are a number of properties that are not yet supported`**. html2canvas is not a "real photo", he tries to interpret and transcribe to objects in the "canvas", or it is not possible to have everything yet.

Comment: My question is not to know if it is implemented but if there is a workaround that someone has found in the meantime. I really thank you for your help but it seems that we don't understand each other: I know html2canvas can't do these things. I wanted to know if some people have worked their way around it somehow. Because, for the text shadows, it's almost there but it's not yet, so I wondered if there were ways to achieve this anyway.
Thank you very much Guilherme.

Comment: They simply do not work, was not completely implemented and not everyone uses complex things in CSS, there are people who do simple things or use with other purposes. If it were possible to work around what is not implemented for sure the lib author would have already made use of this to improve lib.

Comment: Sorry Sir but I don't agree. A workaround might not be bullet proof for each and every cases which would explain why it is not implemented.
That's what a workaround is about. Or any workaround would be a solution by definition. I value your contribution and your attempt to help but most of the back and forth between us is related to the fact that you don't read me completely or assume things.
Are these implemented? No. It was taken for granted from the beginning and it was definitely not my question. When I ask for a potential workaround, it means what it means. Thanks.

Comment: Did you say that I did not read your entire question or did not understand her? Could you explain what exactly I did not understand?

Comment: The fact that I asked for a workaround, not if it was implemented yet. The fact that you ask me twice if the text-shadows works even though I said repeatedly that the render remains exactly the same afterwards (because my initial question was targeting two attributes, not only one of them). And it would be ok, if it wasn't bloating the comment section and diverting fro the original question. It's all fine and, once again, I thank you for your concern, but I just don't want my question to be hi-jacked by side considerations that are off-topic and minimize the chances to get useful info.

Comment: I do not think it was this, it was the way you wrote that led me to misunderstanding, hinted at alternative solution within the "html2canvas", if the question were there is an alternative to the "html2canvas" I would have understood.

There is no reason to exalt yourself, writing is harder than talking,

if people do not understand what you write try changing the words, always keeping the kindness. I think there is a solution without "html2canvas", but I need to test because it implies problems with "CORS"